# Disable Internet Explorer prompt 'the program will open outside of protected mode' when running application through BHO

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, bho, protected-mode

I have written a BHO that will start a console application as soon as the BHO got instantiated. The console application is a simple helper application developed in C# and is placed in local disk C.

When I deployed the BHO on my development machine it worked fine but when deployed on the none development machines, Internet Explorer gives the following popup

[image]

**I just want to get rid of the above popup**

I have tried the following solutions already

- Get the build signed with a digital certificate
- Registry entries as in this link: [Disabling Application Security Prompts](https://support.snapcomms.com/s/article/disabling-application-security-prompts)
- Tried the above in Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Also we cannot disable the protected mode of Internet Explorer as it will allow all other applications including malware.

Comment: Have you tried the **ElevationPolicy** registry key? The registry settings live in **{HKLM/HKCU}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy** with a unique GUID for each application. You should find the key your application lies on and change the Policy value to 3 and restart IE to try again. For more detailed information, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/understanding-the-protected-mode-elevation-dialog).

Comment: @YuZhou yea tried already and it had worked

Comment: Great! I'll put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the **ElevationPolicy** registry key. The registry settings live in **{HKLM/HKCU}\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy** with a unique GUID for each application. You should find the key your application lies on and change the Policy value to 3 and restart IE to try again.

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ieinternals/understanding-the-protected-mode-elevation-dialog).